# Find unique values in a character vector separated by commas and then one-hot encoding

Tags: r, split, one-hot-encoding

Basically I have a vector of strings separated by commas. I'm looking to one-hot encode using the unique values of the strings. I believe I have to first find the unique values (separated by commas) to use as the columns before one-hot encoding, but I'm not sure. For instance, say I have the following character vector:

```
people_names
Bob,Megan,Mike,Sarah
Mike,Sarah
Megan,Sarah
Bob
```

I'm looking to create a resulting one-hot encoded data frame that corresponds to this vector like this:

```
Bob   Megan   Mike   Sarah
  1       1      1       1
  0       0      1       1
  0       1      0       1
  1       0      0       0
```

Thank you for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
people_names = c("Bob,Megan,Mike,Sarah",
                 "Mike,Sarah",
                 "Megan,Sarah",
                 "Bob")

library(tidyverse)

data.frame(people_names) %>%                # create a dataframe
  mutate(id = row_number(),                 # add row id (useful for reshaping)
         value = 1) %>%                     # add a column of 1s to denote existence
  separate_rows(people_names) %>%           # create one row per name keeping relevant info
  spread(people_names, value, fill = 0) %>% # reshape
  select(-id)                               # remove row id

#   Bob Megan Mike Sarah
# 1   1     1    1     1
# 2   0     0    1     1
# 3   0     1    0     1
# 4   1     0    0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, there is a helper function in the `splitstackshape` package that you might find useful. The output is a matrix

```
splitstackshape:::charMat(strsplit(people_names, ","), fill = 0L)
#     Bob Megan Mike Sarah
#[1,]   1     1    1     1
#[2,]   0     0    1     1
#[3,]   0     1    0     1
#[4,]   1     0    0     0
```

From the same package you might also try `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- cSplit_e(
  data.frame(people_names),
  split.col = "people_names",
  sep = ",",
  mode = "binary",
  type = "character",
  fill = 0L,
  drop = TRUE
)
# remove prefix of column names
(out <- setNames(out, sub("people_names_", "", names(out), fixed = TRUE)))
```

**data**

```
people_names = c("Bob,Megan,Mike,Sarah",
                 "Mike,Sarah",
                 "Megan,Sarah",
                 "Bob")
```